# Distorted text rendering in Chrome

Tags: samsung

About a week or two ago I started having font rendering issues in Chrome on my Note 4 (SM-N910V). It's not always, but frequent enough that it's driving me crazy. I have cleared the cache, uninstalled/reinstalled Chrome and still the same issue. When it happens, it's like only part of the text characters are displayed or even complete words are missing, but they're still there because if I highlight and select the blank areas around the partial displayed text, the remaining text will usually finally display. Sometimes they will correct themselves if I scroll down a few. Also, sometimes the text on a page may render perfectly and appear fine, and then while I'm reading it, suddenly just change to the distorted text as I mentioned above. It seems to be specific to Chrome and Chrome Beta, because I installed Firefox, and so far, no issue with text rendering in Firefox. I hope someone more knowledgeable than me can explain what is happening.

I have pictures which should help a lot.
1st pic shows the text at its worst, 2nd shows after I select a word and how it clears up the text in that section, 3rd shows when I select more than one word, how the remaining text area corrects itself also. Then an extra one for another example.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: I'm having that exact issue on my Samsung Note 4 as well. It started after the latest update. Tried uninstalling updates, to no avail. Would greatly appreciate some suggestions, as this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Chrome Beta 71.0.3578.55 fixes the issue!! So far no more text rendering problems! Now I'm scared they'll break it again in a future update

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with Chrome on Samsung Note 4.
My chrome was 71.0.3538.80 and it behaved like you've described.

I've installed Chrome Beta 71.0.3578.55 and it renders correctly so far.

Comment: Chrome Beta 71.0.3578.55 fixed the issue for me also!! So far no more text rendering problems! Now I'm scared they'll break it again in a future update. I'm keeping Firefox on standby